# Use sessions for display notifications?

Tags: php, session, message, notify

I want to show a message when the user logs in:

If the data is correct I will then create a user session and another session named `CORRECT`, then finally check if this session exists in order to show the correct message:

First I create the session:

```
$_SESSION['CORRECT'] = true;
```

And now I check:

```
if($_SESSION['CORRECT']){
    echo = "Correct";
    $_SESSION['CORRECT'] = false;
}else{
    echo = "Incorrect";
}
```

My question: is this the correct way to verify the existence of the session? or should I check it like this?:

```
if($_SESSION['CORRECT'] == true)
```

Comment: might be better to check that the occurance is there before assuming it is. Initially it wont be of course. So `if (isset($_SESSION['CORRECT']) && $_SESSION['CORRECT'] = true){`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1:** `if($_SESSION['CORRECT']){}`

**2:** `if($_SESSION['CORRECT'] == true){}`

Both can be used for checking but they serve different purposes as

`if($_SESSION['CORRECT']){}` will check that `if($_SESSION['CORRECT']){}` is present in the code or not and `if($_SESSION['CORRECT'] == true){}` will check whether the value of `$_SESSION['CORRECT']` is equal to true.